# CSV Search and Replace in Notepad++

Tags: search, csv, replace, notepad++

My colleague is trying to replace all occurrences of `','` with `'·'`.

```
'463897','yes','eng','10529','NULL'
'463930','yes','eng','10544','#primmarkSeg_402208'
'463930','yes','fra','10544','NULL'
```

Becomes

```
'463897'·'yes'·'eng'·'10529'·'NULL'
'463930'·'yes'·'eng'·'10544','#primmarkSeg_402208'
'463930'·'yes'·'fra'·'10544'·'NULL'
```

Same problem when instead of `#` there is a `\`.

It works on my PC. (It even works on my Microsoft Notepad.)

Does anybody have any ideas? Is that an issue with escape characters?

Comment: Could you be more explicit? What do mean by `replace . by .`?

Comment: What conditions make `NULL` to be replaced by `eng` or `fra`?

Comment: {eyeroll} there was an error in my original code...

Comment: What is the problem? Are you referring to the comma in the middle line of the "becomes" text? On my copy of Notepad++ version 6.5.2 all the commas are properly replaced (also with `#` changed to `\`). With what version of Notepad++ are you getting the problem?

Comment: Me too, in my version 6.5.2 all the commas are replaced by middle dots, no problem. In my colleague's version 6.4.5 the commas are not replaced by a middle dot in a sequence ','# or ','\

Answer (score 2):

In notepad++

Find what: `','`
Replace with: `'.'`